# yum install command fails for db4-devel

Tags: ubuntu, installation, yum

I tried to do this command on my Ubuntu machine:

```
yum install db4-devel
```

However I get an error message telling me that the URL could not be parsed correctly. I guess I have to get db4-devel somehow first, but how do I do this?

Comment: In Ubuntu, use `apt-get install`, however the package name will not be the same, depending on the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Answer (score 2):

wget https://public-yum.oracle.com/public-yum-ol6.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/public-yum-ol6.repo

yum install --nogpgcheck -y db4-devel

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to get BerkeleyDB to work on Ubuntu, you can solve this installing libdb-dev and libdb++-dev using apt-get:

```
apt-get install libdb-dev
apt-get install libdb++-dev
```

Comment: Also, you'll not be able to install it simply by running

Comment: apt-get install db4-devel

This package doesn't exist for Ubuntu.